# Server Hardware Configuration Suggestions

Tags: hardware

I'm a student doing internship with a small company with 7-8 employees. Expected growth: Upto 25 employees by next year.

I need some suggestions on what kind of hardware we should use for a server that we are going to setup at our office. This server will run Windows Server 2008 edition with services as follows:

Active Directory

DHCP

File Server

Print Server

Automated backups

Thats all for now. But we want to be future proof and be safe for next 3 years atleast. Any other suggestions welcomed.

Comment: You forgot a little precisation: budget :)

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off-topic per the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with plain Core i7 with consuner grade motherboard and 8Gb RAM + 100Gb SSD for OS and some TB for data.
You've not provided enough infomation to suggest something more specific but but that have to be enough for most of the tasks you'll need. Don't think of 2*socket server at start - not very cost efficient

Answer (score 1):

A good general rule these days: invest in RAM, and in a system with capacity to upgrade to more RAM. Your biggest pain point will be I/O throughput, so minimize that with aggressive caching and a tonne of memory to keep static things like configuration available without a disk call.